# Why does integrating $f_{X,Y}(u,v)$ when trying to find the distribution function of $Z=\max(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

regarding the following problem:

Let X,Y be random variables such that:
$$
f_{X,Y}(u,v)=\begin{cases}
  \frac{3}{4}(u^2+v^2) & -1\leq u\leq1, 0\leq v\leq 1\\    
  0 & \text{otherwise}    
\end{cases}
$$
Find the distribution function of $Z=\max(X,Y)$.

I started by finding the marginal densities, and then I found the distribution function of each X and Y.
Now I know that:

$ F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=P(\max(X,Y)\leq z)=P(X\leq z, Y\leq z)$

Now from the densities I found I can conclude that X,Y are not independent since $f_{X,Y}(u,v)\ne f_{X}(u)*f_{Y}(v)$ , so I can't simply multiply the distributions.
The class notes I am trying to learn from simply integrate it:

$$
 F_Z(z)=\int_{0}^{t}\int_{-1}^{t}f_{X,Y}(u,v)\,du\,dv
$$

But I just don't understand why. Why is that correct? why does that represent the max between X and Y?

Thank!

Comment: The question in your title does not parse.

Comment: No need to compute marginals or test for independence, you just need to find the probability of the event $X \le z,\,Y \le z$, and since you have a density, you get this by integrating the density over this set, which is exactly your integral (assuming that $z=t$).

Comment: @LukasGeyer thanks, so the double integral stands for "and" ?

Comment: @LukasGeyer I think I got it, it is straight from definition

Comment: @LukasGeyer I have another question if I may. The solution sheet divides $F_{Z}(t)$ into 3 separate  regions: $t<0$,$0\leq t\leq 1 $ and $t>1$. Why these regions? (it is not detailed)

Comment: This is just because the cases are slightly different. It is obviously zero for $t<0$, and for $t>1$ you get the same result as for $t=1$, because the additional region you integrate over has zero probability.